# NullPointer while getting Intent from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to get Activity's Intent Extras in Fragment like this:

```
String s = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
```

But have NullPointer. Any ideas?

Comment: how do you send the intent from the other activity

Comment: Please post some more code and also the part from where you are sending the data.

Comment: post appropriate code

Comment: in a fragment, use getArguement() to get bundle sent to that particular fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
if(intent!=null){
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if(bundle!=null){
        String name = bundle.getString("name");
    }
}